# is there a way to declare a type parameter via JSDoc syntax in javascript for typescript to understand

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

this document:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript

doesn't mention type parameters

Questions:

- are type parameters supported via JSDoc type annotations?
- if so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify types with JSDoc in JavaScript for the TypeScript compiler to use...

```
/** @type {Window} */
var myWin;

/** @type {Event} */
var myEvent;

/**
 * @param myStr {string} my parameter
 * @return {string} returns a string
 */
function myFunction(myStr){
    return myStr;
}
```

Available in TypeScript 2.3 and later.

Using generic type parameters:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} thing
 * @return {T}
 */
function getThing(thing){
    return thing;
}
```

Comment: question was about type **parameters**: https://www.google.com/search?q=type+parameters+typescript

Comment: As in generic type parameters?

Comment: Example added for that.

Comment: may i ask for the source of this `@template` syntax?

Comment: more precisely https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1178

thanks!